# Prevent automatic triggering of a click event on client side using the console window

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, click, client-side

Clicks on any HTML element can be triggered merely by using the jQuery function .trigger("click") on any selected element. Automating this click triggering can cause a problem when time taken to perform the click matters, for ex: Time based game.

How do I stop the automatic triggering of the click event that can be done using the developers tools (the console window)?

Alternatively,

How do I differentiate between a click made by a user and a click triggered from the console window?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the person simulating the click does it carefully enough, you can't.

If they just use `$(/*...*/).click()`, it's easy: A real click event will have properties for the mouse position (`pageX` and `pageY`), one created using `$(/*...*/).click()` won't.

But it's fairly easy to create an event that has those properties, so that would only weed out incompetent cheaters rather than all of them.